# Threadprogramming, Heap OutOfMemory

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

i've been programming for the first time with Threads in Java, so here's a pretty much beginners question in terms of Threads.

My Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CollatzRunner implements Runnable {
private int lastNumber = 0;
private int highestCounter = 0;
private int highestValue = 0;

public void run() {     
    while(this.lastNumber < 1000000) {
        this.lastNumber++;
        Collatz c = new Collatz(lastNumber);
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(c.hasNext()) {
            values.add(c.next());
        }

        if(this.highestCounter < values.size()) {
            this.highestCounter = values.size();
            this.highestValue = values.get(0);
        }
        //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + this.lastNumber);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
}
```

and:

```
public class CollatzSimulator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CollatzRunner runner = new CollatzRunner();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(runner, "Thread-1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(runner, "Thread-2");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(runner, "Thread-3");
    Thread t4 = new Thread(runner, "Thread-4");
    //Thread t5 = new Thread(runner, "Thread-5");
    //Thread t6 = new Thread(runner, "Thread-6");
    //Thread t7 = new Thread(runner, "Thread-7");
    //Thread t8 = new Thread(runner, "Thread-8");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    //t5.start();
    //t6.start();
    //t7.start();
    //t8.start();

    System.out.println("bla");
}   
}
```

When running this code if almost immediately get OutOfMemoryError: Heap space. So i suspect i got a pretty major memory leak here. Problem is that i have no experience in this field, therefore i ask on this site.

What i've tried so far:
- Did a heap space dump file (800MB in 5 sec generated)
- tried to set the Collatz instance to null after using it to kill the reference in hope that the garbage collector will free the heap space.

My program is just a little class Collatz, that generates the collatzsequence for a given number and i want to use threads to generate all collatzsequenzes for 0 < n < 1000000.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why on earth are you making 1000000 Collatz objects? Of course it crashes, haha.

Comment: Have you tried running this with only one `Thread`? I'm pretty sure it will crash anyway and the crash isn't caused by a threading issue (although this code WILL have issues regarding race conditions)

Comment: @ Zhuinden: Because our task is to write a class that can calculate the collatz sequence to a given number and i need to compute all the collatz sequences up to 1mio via threads.

Comment: @ aRestless: Yes we've tried that. It will crash depending on your heap space on your local computer. At our laptop it starts crashing at about 150.000 objects.

Comment: and you can't create only one Collatz object?

Comment: What are those threads supposed to do? And what is the purpose of that 1M Collatz objects? Using some resource without good reason is pointless. You can compute those sequences one after the other.

Comment: @ Marco Acierno: Of course i can, but i thought it would be all right the way im doing it right now, because i thought after saying c = null; the reference would be killed and the object would be cleaned up in the heap space. So: I should only use one instance of Collatz() and calculate via different threads all the 1mio sequences with that single object?

Comment: @ laune: As i said im new to ThreadProgramming and this is our first task in university for threadprogramming. It's just our task to use threads to calculate 1mio collatz sequences.

Comment: Looking at @laune's answer: You don't compute all sequences, you're just searching for the longest one. Are you sure it's your task to compute all sequences?

Comment: @ aRestless: Yes, we need to compute all the sequences in order to get their length. After that we can of course free the space occupied by the sequences, because we dont need them for anything other than their length. This is what i tried, but somehow it gets OutOfMemory.

Comment: Just because you put a variable to null it doesn't mean the object will be destroyed immediately, it could stay around until the GC try clear the memory (before the OutOfMemory it try to clear), but you try to create so much objects that he is not able to satisfy your request.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the problem can be found here:

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(c.hasNext()) {
    values.add(c.next());
}
```

From my understanding a Collatz-sequence can get *very* long. What `c.next()` does is to compute the next member of the sequence, this uses nearly no space at all. But concatenating all sequence members into a list takes a huge amount of space. And the more threads you create, the sooner you'll hit that barrier.

If you don't have the option to allocate a *huge* amount of space for the heap, I'm pretty sure the only option would be to write a part of the `values` list out to a file as soon as it exceeds a specific length (you'll have to output it at some point anyway). However, with all that I/O the usage of multithreading will be pretty pointless

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the length of a Collatz sequence for a given starting value: do NOT store the sequence, simply count the number of values Collatz returns:

```
Collatz c = new Collatz(lastNumber);
int length = 0;
while(c.hasNext()) {
    length++;
}

if(this.highestCounter < length) {
    this.highestCounter = length;
    this.highestValue = lastNumber;
}
```

**Later**

After reading about the "thread" challenge: If you have a computer with more than one core, it makes sense to try and search for the longest Collatz sequence up to 1M by running several threads (number of cores) in parallel, *but not using the very same code*. Add arguments startValue and increment to Collatz runner and add this for each iteration, so that the first thread of, say, four, computes 1, 5, 9,... the second 2, 6, 10,... the third 3, 7, 11,... and the fourth 4, 8, 12,....

Comment: `values.get(0)` should be replaced with `lastNumber`, I guess.